# Deploying contracts in truffle while passing parameters of it constructor results in an error

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-migration

I have managed to successfully compile a solidity token contract, the constructor is shown below :

```
function token(uint256 initialsupply, string symbol, string name, uint256 
buyPrice, uint256 sellPrice) public {

    totalSupply = initialsupply * 10**decimals;
    tokenBalance[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    tokenSymbol = symbol;
    tokenName = name;
    buyprice = buyPrice;
    sellprice = sellPrice;
    require(buyprice <= sellprice);
    owner = msg.sender;
```

When using truffle to migrate and deploy the contract I run into an error which is

> Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert

Here is the deploy_contracts.js :

```
var token = artifacts.require("./token.sol");
var newtoken = artifacts.require("./newtoken.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
deployer.deploy(token, 10000, "TOK", "ExampleToken", 20, 10);
deployer.link(token,newtoken);
deployer.deploy(newtoken);
};
```

However, when I add an additional sixth parameter to the constructor in my contract and then deploy the contract with only the above 5 parameters inputted in deploy_contract.js, the contract has no problems migrating the blockchain. So my constructor is now :

> function token(uint256 initialsupply, string symbol, string name, uint256 
>   buyPrice, uint256 sellPrice, uint256 dummy) public {

Is this an issue with truffle when deploying contracts ?

I am using truffle ganache 1.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function has this line:

```
require(buyprice <= sellprice);
```

and you are passing buyPrice = 20 and sellPrice = 10, so it reverts.

Comment: This is embarassing, can't believe I completely missed that. Thanks anyway!